# Selenium Grid, SSL certificate error

Tags: selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I am using selenium Grid
I used selenium attribute trustallSSLCertificates to handle SSL certificate error

It works perfectly in Firefox

but in IE it displays certificate not found
please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do more than just specify that parameter for IE.  Please see the following article for details on getting self-signed certificates working in IE:

http://nirvdrum.com/2010/04/13/how-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificates-in-selenium.html